# Haskell Complex x type where x failed to match actual type Int

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a Haskell function to generate a complex number based on the input, but Ghci keeps complaining about the types. My code is

```
import Data.Complex

pos2com :: RealFloat x => Int -> Int -> Complex x
pos2com x y = ((x-800)/400) :+ ((y-400)/400)
```

And when I tried to load it to Ghci I got

```
? Couldn't match type ‘x’ with ‘Int’
      ‘x’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          pos2com :: forall x. RealFloat x => Int -> Int -> Complex x
        at try.hs:3:1-49
      Expected type: Complex x
        Actual type: Complex Int
    ? In the expression: ((x - 800) / 400) :+ ((y - 400) / 400)
      In an equation for ‘pos2com’:
          pos2com x y = ((x - 800) / 400) :+ ((y - 400) / 400)
    ? Relevant bindings include
        pos2com :: Int -> Int -> Complex x (bound at try.hs:4:1)
```

I guess the problem here should be `(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a` and some errors happened when converting `RealFloat x`, `Fractional x` and `Int`.
Could anyone please kindly lend a hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either: `x` and `y` need to both be type `x`:

```hs
pos2com :: Fractional x => x -> x -> Complex x
pos2com x y = ((x - 800) / 400) :+ ((y - 400) / 400)
```

Or, you need to convert them to `Fractional`s first with [`fromIntegral`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral):

```hs
pos2com :: Fractional x => Int -> Int -> Complex x
pos2com x y = ((fromIntegral x - 800) / 400) :+ ((fromIntegral y - 400) / 400)
```

Comment: Thank you for giving such a direct and clear solution!

Answer (score 3):

The important thing to understand when navigating numeric operations in Haskell is that most operations do not change types -- there is no automatic conversion like you see in many languages.  So when you have

```
(x - 800) / 400
```

Whatever type `x` is, the result will be that same type.  So here `x` is an `Int`, which means `(x - 800) / 400` will b an `Int`  (and then there will be a missing instance error because you can't use `/` to divide `Int`s -- you need to use integer division `div`).

So constructing the `Complex x` fails because `Int` is not *necessarily* the same type as `x`.

When we do need to convert, we usually use either `fromIntegral` (to convert *from* integral types), or `realToFrac` (to convert *from* fractional ones).

Comment: Thank you for explaining the underlying idea and concepts!